# Concatenation changing the type of result

Tags: java, string

I have been asked a question(looks to be simple):
There is a

```
String s1 = "ABC"
```

and there are two other Strings as

```
String s2= s1+ 2+ 3+ 5;
String s3 = 2+3+5+s1;
```

What will be the out put??

Now if you print the both the Strings then `s2= "abc235"` and `s3 = "10abc".`
 Now I am bit confused with results.
I think it is because the operation starts from Left and and its move on it changes its type and since first was the String, it became as "abc2" and then concatenating other operands.
Can some please provide possible explanation?? 
Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 5):

Basically, operator associativity in Java means that your first expression is equivalent to:

```
String s2 = ((( s1 + 2 ) + 3 ) + 5 );
```

This means: evaluate `s1 +2`. Because one of the operands is string, the operator is string concatenation, and the result is string: `ABC2`.

Therefore the next `+` is also string concatenation, and the result is string: `ABC23`;

And so, the last `+` is also string concatenation, and the result is string: `ABC235`.

While the second is equivalent to:

```
String s2 = ((( 2 + 3 ) + 5 ) + s1 );
```

The first expression has two integer operands. So it is an addition operator, and its result is integer: 5.

The next `+` also has two integer operands, so the result is still integer: `10`;

But the final `+` has a `String` operand, so the operation is string concatenation, and the result is string: `10ABC`.

Comment: It's not the precedence, it's the associativity.

Comment: Right. I mixed my terms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes operations starts from left to write.

For s2, s1 type is String and hence when you do "+" with 2 it concatenates to String (intenally using StringBuilder) it appends to existing String and hence you see output as abc235.

While for s3, it first evaluates the right hand side of assignment from left to right and recognizes that first argument to + is number and left is number as well, so it keeps on adding the numbers and finally append's String at the end and hence you see output as "10abc".

Comment: ohk how about you do this way :
s1 + (2+3+5)

Comment: @vinodbazari Try it and you will see (the result).

Comment: @Tom : I have the result , but still superised with the compiler behavior.

Comment: @vinodbazari What would you do if you see a math expression with parenthese? Would you evaluate them first and then the rest? If so, why should the compiler behave differently?